# Power Automate - Not getting GUID for selected Email / case record from Queue Items view

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, power-automate, dynamics-crm-365, power-platform

When I am trying to get the GUID (or any record level attribute) for Email or case using "Email Message" or Case from the Queue Item view, it is coming as blank/null.

Step 1-
[image]

Step 2-
[image]

How to get GUID of the selected record in Power Automate.

Ultimately I want selected Email's QueueItem ID, which is present in output of selected email object, but how to get it in PowerAutomate.

[image]

Comment: Ultimately I am looking for QueueItem GUID, which I can see in the selected record's output. How can I read it from that JSON.

Comment: GUID != string, you're trying to write a GUID variable into a string field.